# How to match undefined number of arguments or how to match known keywords in a regular expression

Tags: ruby, regex

Some questions about regex, simple for you but not for me.
a) I want to match a string using a regular expression.

```
keyword term1,term2,term3,.....termN
```

The number of terms is undefined. I know how to begin but after I am lost ;-)

```
\(\w+)(\s+) but after ?\i
```

b) A little bit more complicated:

```
capitale france paris,england london,germany berlin, ...
```

I want to separate the couples ai bi in order to analyse them.

c) how to check if one among several keywords are present or not ?

```
direction LEFT,RIGHT,UP,DOWN
```

Comment: There is no delineation between keyword and a1 and b1 in your examples. Can you give real world examples?

Comment: What determines when the comma-separated list of terms terminates? Or does the keyword automatically signify that the remaining part of the string contains *only* terms?

Comment: end of line. No terms would be an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a good task for a regular expression as you want to use it. In addition, you're asking several questions that have to be addressed in several steps; Determining duplicates isn't part of a regex's skill set.

Regex assume there is a repeating pattern, and if you're trying to parse an entire line of indeterminate number of elements at once, it will take a very complex pattern.

I'd recommend you use a simple [`split(',')`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/String.html#method-i-split) to break the line on commas:

```
'keyword term1,term2,term3,.....termN'.split(',')
# => ["keyword term1", "term2", "term3", ".....termN"]

'capitale france paris,england london,germany berlin, ...'.split(',')
# => ["capitale france paris", "england london", "germany berlin", " ..."]
```

Once you have the line split, if you want to break apart complex entries on white-space, use a bare [`split`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/String.html#method-i-split):

```
'capitale france paris,england london,germany berlin, ...'.split(',').map(&:split)
# => [["capitale", "france", "paris"],
#     ["england", "london"],
#     ["germany", "berlin"],
#     ["..."]]
```

This will all fall apart if there are embedded commas in a field. The data you're working with looks like CSV (comma-separated values), and that spec allows for them. *IF* you're working with true CSV data, then use the [CSV](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/csv/rdoc/index.html) library that comes with Ruby. It will save your sanity and keep you from trying to reinvent a wheel.

To count keywords you can do something like:

```
entries = 'capitale france paris,england london,germany berlin, ...'.split(',').map(&:split)
# => [["capitale", "france", "paris"],
#     ["england", "london"],
#     ["germany", "berlin"],
#     ["..."]]

keywords = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = 0 }
entries.each do |entry|
  entry.each do |e|
    keywords[e] += 1 if e[/\b(?:france|england|germany)\b/i]
  end
end
keywords # => {"france"=>1, "england"=>1, "germany"=>1}
```

There are other ways to do this using various methods in Enumerable and Array, but this demonstrates the technique. I used a pattern to locate the keyword hits because it's fast and can find the keyword within a string. You could do a lookup using `index` or `find` or `any?` but they'll slow your code as the list of keywords grows.